# query to find out all defined triggers and search of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

We have hundreds of tables with poor documentation.

Are there any queries which:

1. Will print out which tables have triggers and name of those triggers
2. Can search text within currently defined stored procedures?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy's got you covered: http://www.alberton.info/sql_server_meta_info.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the name of each trigger, the name of the parent object that the trigger is attached to, and the T-SQL definition of the trigger:

```sql
SELECT [TriggerName] = t.name
    , [ParentObject] = o.name
    , [TriggerDefinition] = m.definition
FROM sys.triggers t
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON t.parent_id = o.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON t.object_id = m.object_id;
```

You could add a where clause similar to `WHERE m.definition LIKE '%Test%'` if you want to limit the results to trigger code containing the word `Test`.